# Can I connect to a Bluetooth Device without unpairing it in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I have a dualshock 4, which I connect to using bluetooth. However, everytime I want to re connect to it after disconnecting, I have to unpair it, then repair it. Is there a bypass for this? I have tried doing this through connected devices, but it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in my case, all I had to do was to press the PS button. I also found that you could go Windows+A or Windows+I if you were connecting to Audio or visually